# What types of sounds do sperm whales produce?

Tags: zoology, marine-biology, bioacoustics, echolocation

Sperm whales produce echolocation clicks, what are the other types of clicks and other sounds they can produce?

Comment: Welcome (again). You'll find that when you browse the help centre it'll point out the need for showing your own research when asking a question. Since you self-answered (encouraged, though not usually so quickly done!), then showing research in the Q seems redundant - on this occasion.

Comment: There's an article here about that: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-84126-8

Answer (score 3):

Sperm whales produce echolocation clicks, known as **usual/ regular clicks** (Madsen et al., 2002) and **buzzes/ creaks** (Gordon, 1987), while they are actively foraging underwater. These are distinguished from other types of clicks based on the repetition rate (known as the inter click interval).

Sperm whales also produce **slow clicks** (Gordon, 1987), **surface/ coda creaks** (whitehead, 2003), **rapid/ fast clicks**, and **chirrups**. These sounds are thought to be used for communication and/ or to scan conspecifics.

Non click sounds include **squeals, pips, short trumpets,** and **trumpets** (Pace et al., 2021).

**References:**

Gordon, J. C. D. The behaviour and ecology of sperm whales off Sri Lanka (Doctoral dissertation, Darwin College, Cambridge, 1987).

Madsen, P. T. et al. Sperm whale sound production studied with ultrasound time/depth-recording tags. J. Exp. Biol. 205(13), 1899–1906 (2002).

Pace, D.S., Lanfredi, C., Airoldi, S. et al. Trumpet sounds emitted by male sperm whales in the Mediterranean Sea. Sci Rep 11, 5867 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-84126-8. Available from: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-84126-8

Whitehead, H. Sperm Whale: Social Evolution in the Ocean (The University of Chicago Press, Chicago, 2003).Return to ref 8 in article

Comment: Nice one. Please take our [tour] and refer as and when to the [help] for guidance. Enjoy biology.